# Want to change my site root

Tags: directory, site-url, deployment, home-url

Hello I have a wordpress site that has a url at some ip address. Now what I want to do change the url. Instead of http://"My IP Address", I want it http://"My IP Address"/wordpress. instead.Is there a way to do this in wordpress?

My document folder is called wordpress. It is stored  in /var/www/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your site `http://"ip address"`

[image]

- go to `http://"ip address"/wp-admin/options-general.php`

[image]

- in the General Settings change the `Site Address (URL)` from `http://"My IP Address"` to `http://"My IP Address"/wordpress`

[image]

- Its done

[image]

Comment: Ah, I think you forgot to tell me to move my root document folder as well. It needs to be in a folder called wordpress.

Comment: not necessarily if your wordpress is http://"My IP Address"/folder that will work as well but use the wordpress address (URL) ""http://"My IP Address"/folder""